# What is DTOs in Ethereum?

Tags: nethereum, openethereum

I saw this in

http://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/introduction/rpc/#dtos

Basically, there is an article whose title is DTO and then there is no explanation whatsoever what s DTO

What is it?

What can it be?

What does it stand for?

Searching on the web doesn't show any clear result. Basically it shows up on a bunch of site talking about nethereum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to be found in the link you provided:

> There are various RPC **Data transfer objects** for Block, Transaction, FilterInput, and BlockParameter, to name a few.

I agree that they could have formatted the sentence better, e.g. by capitalizing every word and appending the acronym within trailing brackets.

There's nothing special about "DTOs" in Ethereum. They are a specific data structure used in Nethereum.